# "Save result buffer" and "Visualize tree" via python-weka-wrapper-0.3.8?

Tags: python, weka

Is there a way to achieve "Save result buffer" and "Visualize tree" options that are available in the weka tool, *through weka-python-wrapper also*? (As the weka tool does not provide scripting options). Not able to find it in the python-weka-wrapper-0.3.8 documentation. Please help or direct me where to find the solution.

Screenshot of the Weka explorer tool with those two options visible

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [python-weka-wrapper](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper) library does not come with a GUI, hence the question is a bit misplaced. However, this is covered in the examples section of the python-weka-wrapper documentation ([Build classifier on dataset, print model and draw graph](http://pythonhosted.org/python-weka-wrapper/examples.html#build-classifier-on-dataset-print-model-and-draw-graph)). The code to this is also available from the [classifiers.py](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper-examples/blob/master/src/wekaexamples/classifiers/classifiers.py) code example (look for comment `# build a classifier and output model`).

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am aware that python-weka-wrapper does not come with GUI. I have rephrased the question now to avoid confusion. I wanted to know if the same aforementioned two functionalities can be achieved through scripting (the same outputs i mean) using the wrapper. The code helps, thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can generate the same outputs. However, the tree visualization will look nicer using python-weka-wrapper. ;-)